# Determine if subscribers have my domain enabled?

Tags: package, mydomain, 2gmp

We are developing 2GMP.
We need to know if we can programmatically query some record on devhub to find out if there are subscribers that do not have my domain enabled.
Is there a way for this?

If we query `PackageSubscriber` object we only receive information about subscriber `OrgId` and `OrgName` but not the Domain

```
SELECT Id,InstalledStatus,InstanceName,MetadataPackageId,MetadataPackageVersionId,OrgKey,OrgName,OrgStatus,OrgType,ParentOrg,SystemModstamp FROM PackageSubscriber
```

Comment: I think this can be achieved using Feature Management by creating subscriber-to-LMO feature parameter. You can set the boolean parameter by checking below code.
String url=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
if(url.contains('.my'){...}

Comment: This is an interesting idea, however, doesn't apply to me since my client don't want to send the package to AppExchange and pass the security review. So, unfortunately I can't use subscriber-to-LMO feature parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since Winter 2022 every org has My Domain enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_my_domain_enforced.htm&type=5&release=234)

So there is no more org without My Domain enabled as of now.